# call variable that has been grouped by

Tags: r, dplyr

Some sample data:

```
 df <- data.frame(lang = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3), 
                  answer = rep(c("1", "2", "3"), each=3))
```

I am getting an error when I try to call a variable that I recently grouped by:

```
 df2 <- df %>%
   Total = count(lang) %>%  # count is short hand for tally + group_by()
   filter(answer=='2') %>% 
   mutate(prop = NROW(answer)/NROW(Total)) 

 Error in group_vars(x) : object 'lang' not found
```

I would like a new column on my dataframe that says the proportion of the answer '2' to total observations in each level of `lang`. So how many times does '2' occur in 'A' in proportion to the total number of observations in 'A'?

Comment: a new column onto your data frame? what is the desired output of that column? (9 entries)
or do you mean one value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that does what you want:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(lang) %>% 
  summarize(
    prop = length(lang[answer==2])/n()
  )
```

Here, we group by the variable or variables that you want set as the unique groups you want to get the proportion of and then use `summarize` to calculate the length of the vector of one of the variables where answer is equal to 2 and divide that by the number of rows in the grouping. If, for whatever reason, you want the prop column AND the answer column, just change `summarize` to `mutate`.

The reason you were getting the error about not finding `lang` is because  `count` needs to be used as a function like mutate, i.e.

```
df %>% 
  count(lang, name = "Total")
```

You could achieve the same thing adapting your code, but you should use `add_count` (so your answer column is preserved) or `mutate(Total = n())`. However, group_by was designed to address problems such as this and is definitely worth spending some time to learn about.

```
df %>% 
  add_count(lang, name = "Total") %>% 
  filter(answer == 2) %>% 
  add_count(lang, name = "Twos") %>% 
  distinct(lang, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(prop = Twos/Total) %>% 
  select(lang, prop)
```

Comment: thank you! and thank you for explaining why count didn't work - this should be clearer for me next time I try to use something like this!

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate solution with data.table**

I prefer to use `data.table` than data frames everywhere personally. Here is the implementation with that method, although admittedly it looks a bit more cryptic than the solution in `dplyr` (The syntax to accomplish something like this may be more involved, but getting used to it ends up giving you a whole bag of tricks, and with simple queries the syntax actually looks better)

You end up trying to use "lang" like its a variable, when its a name of a column.

To get the values requested, `0.3333` for each,

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[, nrow(.SD[answer == 2])/nrow(.SD), by="lang"]

   lang        V1
1:    A 0.3333333
2:    B 0.3333333
3:    C 0.3333333
```

(the special variable `.SD` allows you to manipulate every subset of the data, split by `by`)

Comment: I was hoping to use group_by() because I'd like the proportion of 2:the other entries for lang=='A', 'B', and 'C', not just for 'A'

Comment: so your desired output is 3 numbers?

Comment: in this pretend dataset, yes

Comment: I'm surprised by your clarity comment; data.table notation is rarely considered clearer than tidyverse notation when it's done concisely and certainly not for beginners to R who are the target audience of this sort of question.

Comment: Ah, well I posted that before I edited my post with the .SD stuff which is admittedly a bit less clear.
His question originally sounded like he was looking for 1 number, where the notation was much more basic, `nrow(df[lang == "A" & answer == 2]) / nrow(df[lang == "A"])`

Comment: someone thinks "this answer is not useful" with the downvote? really? this is still a valid way to do it

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'm not the person who downvoted, but my R says `by = "lang"` isn't used (with data.table loaded) so there might be a typo or another package that's required.

Comment: was data.table loaded *last*? `df[i,j,by]` is standard and this works for me. dplyr might be overriding it if you didn't `library(data.table)` as the last one

Comment: Updated to reflect that this is actually not clearer and just an alternate solution (and upvoted you, GenesRus. ty for the feedback)